# magento 2 images on category page not visible

Tags: magento2, image, csv

If I import products with csv the image is not visibly at the category page. If I go to the product page the image is showing. How is that possible. 
base, thumbnail, small image and swatch are fine.

I use magento 2.1.6

Answer (score 1):

The category pages use the flat index tables, the product page not. So your index is not up to date.

Is your index configuration "update on save"? Then the product import was not updated by the import and you need to update it manually with this shell command:

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_attribute
```

Is it "scheduled"? Then make sure that your cronjob is running and give it some time to update. It still might be necessary to update the index
as above.

Comment: thanx voor you anser but the problem is not solved. I updated the index with ssh but nothing changed.

Comment: Just in case: did you clear the cache afterwards?

Comment: I cleared the cache but nothing happend. Do I miss something? I don't understand why the image on the product list is showing but only shows in the productpage and in the admin.

Comment: May be it sounds weird but can you check if there is any error on that particular page. As once in my case size of image is too large that it gives error. When i optimize the images . Every thing worked fine

Answer (score 0):

You may be a victim of [this bug](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9276). Try running the command:

`php bin/magento catalog:images:resize`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause is somehow the value for attribute image, thumbnail, small_image is set no-selection for the desired store, just check the catalog_product_entity_varchar table for these attribute, if this is the case, delete these records should resolve the problem, at least for my case.